# memmove only copies the first element

Tags: c++

This is my input array

> 0 0 0 3 4 5 6 7 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

I am expecting the output array to be like this using memmove or memcpy

> 0 3 4 5 6 7 6 7 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

This is my code

```
int front = 3,rear = 7;
memmove(ele+1,ele+front,rear-front);
```

As far my understanding of memmove goes, it copies rear-front (4) bytes from ele+front (3) to ele+1 (1).
 Then how is the output wrong ?

Output of the above code:

> 0 3 0 3 4 5 6 7 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

Comment: `(rear-front) * sizeof *ele`

Comment: ... because your array is integers (typically 4 bytes each) and you're moving 4 bytes (or one integer).

Comment: Understood and that worked. I don't see any option to accept a comment as an answer :)

Comment: The question should show how `ele` is declared and values set up

Comment: Do *not* use `memcpy` for this.  If the source and destination areas overlap, the effect is undefined behaviour (read "very bad").

Comment: T *ele = new T[20];   //T is a generic type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The prototype of memmove is:

```
void * memmove ( void * destination, const void * source, size_t num );
```

Where num is counted in bytes (as you also mention in you question).

In your question you omitted the type of "ele". When "ele" is of type char* or something equivalent (such as uint8_t*) then the code should work as expected.
However if "ele" is of type int* then each item in your array usually takes 4 bytes (for a 32bit processor) and that would explain why only one array item is copied.

You should call memmove with the size multiplied by the size of each element like so:

memmove(target, source, elem_count * sizeof(elem_type) )